# DynamoDB Local Basic PHP Setup

Tags: php, windows, amazon-dynamodb

I am having some trouble connecting to my local instance of DynamoDB.  I am launching the server by running the following at the command prompt:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin>java -Djava.library.path=D:\DynamoDB\DynamoDBLoca
l_lib -jar D:\DynamoDB\DynamoDBLocal.jar
```

My PHP code looks like this:

```
<?

require './aws-autoloader.php';
use \Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;

$client = \Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
    'profile' => 'default',
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'base_url' => 'http://localhost:8000'
));


// create test table    
$client->createTable(array(
    'TableName' => 'errors',
    'AttributeDefinitions' => array(
        array(
            'AttributeName' => 'id',
            'AttributeType' => 'N'
        ),
        array(
            'AttributeName' => 'time',
            'AttributeType' => 'N'
        )
    ),
    'KeySchema' => array(
        array(
            'AttributeName' => 'id',
            'KeyType'       => 'HASH'
        ),
        array(
            'AttributeName' => 'time',
            'KeyType'       => 'RANGE'
        )
    ),
    'ProvisionedThroughput' => array(
        'ReadCapacityUnits'  => 10,
        'WriteCapacityUnits' => 20
    )
));
```

When I execute the createTable() command, I don't see any activity in my command prompt window where the server is running and I get the following error:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Aws\Common\Exception\InstanceProfileCredentialsException' with message 'Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server. When you are not running inside of Amazon EC2, you must provide your AWS access key ID and secret access key in the "key" and "secret" options when creating a client or provide an instantiated Aws\Common\Credentials\CredentialsInterface object. ([curl] 28: Connection timed out after 5008 milliseconds [url] http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\AWS\Aws\Common\InstanceMetadata\InstanceMetadataClient.php:85 Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\AWS\Aws\Common\Credentials\RefreshableInstanceProfileCredentials.php(52): Aws\Common\InstanceMetadata\InstanceMetadataClient->getInstanceProfileCredentials()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\AWS\Aws\Common\Credentials\AbstractRefreshableCredentials.php(54): Aws\Common\Credentials\RefreshableInstanceProfileCredentials->refresh()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\AWS\Aws\Common\Signature\SignatureV4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\AWS\Aws\Common\InstanceMetadata\InstanceMetadataClient.php on line 85
```

I am a little confused because it seems like the code isn't hitting the local server what-so-ever which would obviously prevent anything else from working.  Any input/thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hate to answer this so quickly but it turned out that the key/secret are required even for local DynamoDB usage.  It's odd this isn't mentioned on the AWS site but here is the working code for connecting, after that all other examples have worked:

```
$client = \Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => 'YOUR_KEY',
        'secret' => 'YOUR_SECRET',
    ],
    'region' => 'us-west-2',
    'endpoint' => 'http://localhost:8000'
));
```

Comment: DynamoDB Local does need credentials, though they don't have to be real: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.DynamoDBLocal.html#Tools.DynamoDBLocal.UsageNotes

Comment: In this case though, the error came from the SDK itself, because the SDK needs credentials to create a signature for a request. Again, they don't have to be real credentials, since you are not actually authenticating with AWS to access DynamoDB Local.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyLindblom!  Things are actually going quite smoothly now and I am beginning the process of migrating 5GB of Mongo data over to DynamoDB.  Thanks again and take care!

Comment: Update: new versions are not working with `base_url`, since the parameter name was replaced with `endpoint`. I found it out here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/485. The answer is still correct, but would need this fix

Comment: For anyone struggling to connect with this, only numbers and letters now working for the key and secret (I was using 'YOUR_KEY' which was failing)